# Convert Values to top 10 scale

Tags: mysql, valueconverter

Here is the problem. I have four columns that I want to present in a select query.
But, I want the RSV column to have a 10-1 scale instead of its + and - values.
The greatest number +8,6 should get 10. Several of the values in the bottom can have 1.
I have absolutley no idea how to solve this...

Nr is race horses start number. 
A race can also contain less than fifteen horses

```
    Nr  RPO    RSP     RSV

    1   10     9       +5,3
    2   9      10      +8,6 
    3   8      7       -2,7
    4   7      8       +3,8
    5   6      4       +4,3 
    6   5      6       -1,0
    7   4      5       +3,3
    8   3      1       +6,6
    9   2      1       +2,1
    10  1      1       +3,8
    11  1      3       +2,9
    12  1      2       -2,1
    13  1      1       +1,0
    14  1      1       -1,0
    15  1      1       +2,4
```

Last column shows the output:

```
               
Nr  RPO RSP RSV      RSVOutput
2   9   10  8,6      10
8   3   1   6,6      9
1   10  9   5,3      8
5   6   4   4,3      7
4   7   8   3,8      6
10  1   1   3,8      5
7   4   5   3,3      4
11  1   3   2,9      3
15  1   1   2,4      2
9   2   1   2,1      1
13  1   1   1        1
6   5   6   -1       1
14  1   1   -1       1
12  1   2   -2,1     1
3   8   7   -2,7     1
```

```
SELECT *
FROM rank
ORDER BY Nr
```

Comment: You want to show 10 instead of +8,6 in `RSV` column. Is that what you want to achieve? Can you post your expected output?

Comment: post your wished result because it hard to understand what you want. är oxo nyfiken

Comment: The thing is that I should use values ​​later in a crosstab query and want the same type of values.

Comment: why Nr=15 you made `RSVOutput=1` and Nr=11 you made `RSVOutput=3` ? something special here?

Comment: I sorted descending on RSV column. The Nr column is race horses.

Comment: you didnt understand my question , Nr=15 why RSVOutput=1 and not RSVOutput=2 ?

Comment: Ahh, my misstake echo_me. Should be 2. Fixed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  Nr, RPO, RSP, RSV,
  CASE WHEN @row>1 THEN @row:=@row-1 ELSE 1 END RSVOutput
FROM
  yourtable, (SELECT @row:=11) rows
ORDER BY
  RSV DESC
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f688d/3).

Comment: do you really need this r near of 11 ?

Comment: the OP he dont have `RSVOutput = 2` in his result

Comment: The column 'Nr' is racing horses start number. A race can also contain less than fifteen horses. Does the code work in these cases?

Comment: @echo_me no you don't need an r alias after the select, i'll remove it, but RSVOutput is correct, i noticed it but i thought it was a typo

Comment: @Nyfiken yes it will work even if there are less than fifteen rows, but if there are less than 9 there will be no RSVOutput=1, is this correct?

Comment: @fthiella yes it is correct. And it was a typo, sorry. I'm very happy with this solution!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623494/convert-decimal-value-to-top-10
Need some assistance. Can't get this to work.

Comment: @Nyfiken i added my answer there, please have a look at it, hope it's okay!